# Check if list of dates is complete in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, time-series

I have a text file with a header containing the start and end dates of a time series. The rest of the file contains 3 columns: start day, end day and value - as shown below.

```
19580101 20181231
19580101 19580131     4.2
19580201 19580228    -1.6
19580301 19580331    -4.9
.
.
.
20181001 20181031    -8.2
20181101 20181130    -3.8
20181201 20181231     3.1
```

I want to display the values on a graph over time, but first want to check that the dates are complete.

Here is a portion of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf('file.txt',header=None)
head = df.loc[0] #extract header
df = df.drop(0) #delete first line

date_seq = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:,0]) #convert column 0 to datetime

start_date = str(int(head[0])) #'19850101'
end_date = str(int(head[1])) #'20181231'

#synthesize date range:
strt = pd.to_datetime(start_date,format='%Y%m%d')
ends = pd.to_datetime(end_date,format='%Y%m%d')
date_rng = pd.date_range(start=strt, end=ends, freq='MS')

#compare extracted and synthesized date sequences:
diff = date_seq - date_rng
print diff.sum()
```

The output is: 0 days 00:00:00

This seems somewhat inefficient. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: You could make the datetime your index and then do something like: pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max()).difference(df.index)

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the diff of the series rather than creating a second series.

```
df['date_check'] = df.date_col.diff()
df.date_check.value_counts()
```

This will give you a list of all the gaps in your series. This will also work with a `groupby` if you have a number of series in your data frame.